# Currency check whether € or $

Tags: vba, excel, format

I want to program a sub that checks whether a value in a cell is formatted as currency and then checks whether this currency is € or anything else.
Based on the result the user should be prompted an InputBox to enter the actual exchange rate between currency given and euro. Then the sub does some math and puts the calculated € value formatted as currency in € back into the cell.

Looking through SO I found the idea to use `.NumberFormat` on the cell's value and then use `InStr(1, cellValue, "€") = 0` to check whether it is a € currency or not.

Now I use the German version of Excel and a short test with `Debug.Print Range("A1").NumberFormat` gives me this: `#,##0.00 $`. So even if my Excel shows me a € as currency, VBA gives me $ instead.

How can I work around this? I assume that `#,##0.00 $` is Excel's backend logic while it uses the standard language as its frontend logic and displays the currency based on language selected?

Comment: `If InStr(1,cell.NumberFormatLocal,"€") Then DoSomeStuff`. The key is NumberFormatLocal

Comment: Tried it. Output of `.NumberFormatLocal` is "Standard". Tried it with € and $ format. Both the same.

Comment: Oh! How strange. It gives me my local currency. Another one of those fiddly locale things. Gary's answer should always work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The cell I tried it on was empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the currency symbol by using the **.Text** property rather than the **.Value** property:

```
Sub MoneyCheck()
    Dim st As String
    st = ActiveCell.Text
    ch = Left(st, 1)
    If ch = "$" Then
        MsgBox "Dollars"
    ElseIf ch = "€" Then
        MsgBox "Not Dollars"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what a simple solution! Thank you.

Comment: I would change it to do an InStr instead as the above will fail for negatives under the default style of having the negative sign in front of the currency symbol (or for countries where the symbol comes to the right etc)

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you should see $* as it is system default currency and $€ if it's, for example specific Euro or $£ if specifically Pounds.
But you can never be sure the currency displayed is the right one. OS language/location settings, Excel settings and Excel/VBA language all have influence.

The best way is to enter the currency in an additional column, for example enter EUR before (or after) the value. It's by far the savest solution.